# querySelectorAll() returns list of empty nodes when used with jsdom

Tags: node.js, jsdom, selectors-api

I am trying to scrape some information from wikipedia pages with my `Node.js` app, using `jsdom`. Here is an example of what I'm doing:

```
jsdom.env({
    url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Gates",
    features: {
        FetchExternalResources: ['script'],
        ProcessExternalResources: ['script'],
        SkipExternalResources: false,
    },
    done: function (err, window) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error: ", err)
            return;
        }

        var paras = window.document.querySelectorAll('p');
        console.log("Paras: ", paras)
    }
});
```

The weird thing is that `querySelectorAll('p')` returns a `NodeList` of empty elements:

```
Paras:  NodeList {
  '0': HTMLParagraphElement {},
  '1': HTMLParagraphElement {},
  '2': HTMLParagraphElement {},
  '3': HTMLParagraphElement {},
  '4': HTMLParagraphElement {},
  '5': HTMLParagraphElement {},
  '6': HTMLParagraphElement {},
  '7': HTMLParagraphElement {},
  ...
  62': HTMLParagraphElement {} }
```

Any idea on what could be the problem? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I got the same result when replacing `window.document.querySelectorAll('p')` with `window.document.getElementsByTagName('p')`

Comment: Have you found any solution so far?

Comment: Unfortunately, no :/

Answer (score 6):

The elements are not empty it just won't show you the result in a console log.
You have to access data on them (`textContent` for it for example)

Try this:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(dom.window.document.getElementsByTagName("p")).map(p => {
    console.log(p.textContent);
}
```